# ModEvasive Not Sending Email Alerts

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, apache-2.2

I have installed ModEvasive on Ubuntu/Apache 14.04 server. Mod is working correctly and blocks DDOS attacks. But it doesn't trigger any email. I have correctly mentioned DOSEmailNotify in .conf file. Also the log file shows only a PID.

What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `libapache2-mod-evasive` module was compiled to use the default/typical mail binary location available on most Linux platforms, but on Ubuntu, the mail binary is located in a different location.

it tries to send use `/bin/mail`. but on Ubuntu, it' usually under `/usr/bin/mail`..

The simplest fix is to create a symbolic link from `/bin/mail` to the currently active mail program: `/etc/alternatives/mail`

- **ln -s /etc/alternatives/mail /bin/mail**

bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache-mod-evasive/+bug/605679

Comment: Tried it. But still didn't receive any email. Log only shows '50815' guess its PID.

Comment: apache error log has this line - [Fri Aug 15 15:18:04.921756 2014] [evasive20:error] [pid 51057] [client 127.0.0.1:42930] client denied by server configuration:

Comment: looks like that line just says mod_evasive has banned the user. nothing really substantive to your issue. my answer describes the most common issue for this happening. it might not be compatible with, or you might not have the program installed.

Comment: try this: delete the symlink you made. then try:  apt-get install heirloom-mailx . make a new symlink. restart everything, and try again. if this does not help, make sure you raise LogLevel to Debug, and see if this helps bring about more detailed information in your error log.

Comment: How to check/delete existing symbolic link ? I tried `find /etc/alternatives/mail -type l` It says `No such file or directory`. But `find /bin/mail -type l` gives `/bin/mail`. Is it correct ?

Comment: `:~$ ls -l /bin/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug 15 17:28 /bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail`. But there is no `/etc/alternatives/mail`

Comment: also `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mail: No such file or directory`

Comment: to delete a symlink, just remove it the same way you would any other file (*rm /path/to/symlink*). /etc/alternatives/mail is a link to the current default mail program. this is usually set by your package manager, when update-alternatives is installed. make sure heirloom-mailx is installed, and try linking /bin/mail to /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx instead. or install update-alternatives, and repeat the process outlined above.

Comment: @ChamingaD  I had to delete the log file in order for the email to be sent. if the log file for a given IP already exists, the email won't be sent. at least in my experience.